# Xamarin ListView как обновить отображение?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

Через кнопки пытаюсь взаимодействовать со списком, добавлять/удалять элементы, изменять размер строк(ячеек) через Slider. Но всё это не отображается, проверил через дебаггер, свойства изменяются(в списке больше/меньше объектов), но визуально всё остается по прежнему.

Как обновить отображение измененного источника и изменение размера ячеек?

```
public class RootPage : ContentPage
    {
        ListView listView;
        public RootPage ()
        {
            listView = new ListView() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand };
            listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCustomCell));
            listView.ItemsSource = new CustomText[] { new CustomText("asd", "bsd"), new CustomText("abra", "kadabra") };
            listView.HasUnevenRows = true;
            var slider = new Slider() {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                Maximum = 300,
                Minimum = 100
            };
            slider.ValueChanged += Slider_ValueChanged;
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Spacing = 20,
                Children = {
                    listView,
                    slider
                }
            };
        }

        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.RowHeight = (int)e.NewValue;
        }
    }



public class CustomText
    {
        public string T1 { get; set; }
        public string T2 { get; set; }
        public CustomText(string t1, string t2)
        {
            T1 = t1;
            T2 = t2;
        }
    }
    public class MyCustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public MyCustomCell()
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            var label2 = new Label();

            label1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("T1"));
            label2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("T2"));

            var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Olive,
                Children = {
                    label1,
                    label2
                }
            };

            View = horizontalLayout;
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для подобных целей использую привязки с inotifypropertychanged

Answer (score 1):

Как видно из Вашего кода, Вы присваиваете свойству ItemsSource только что созданный массив в конструкторе класса RootPage. Это значит, что последующие изменения массива никак не отобразятся в listView.
Обычно для таких целей используются привязки - [Binding](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php)-и. Кроме того, коллекция, которую вы хотите отобразить и высота строки, которую хотите обновлять, должны быть публичными свойствами. 
Если вы не используете [MVVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel), то можно предположить, что вам пригодятся [Dependency property](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level4/4_3.php), а нужный Вам код в классе RootPage будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
public class RootPage : ContentPage
{
    ListView listView;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomTextCollectionProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(
                "CustomTextCollection", 
                typeof(ObservableCollection<CustomText>),
                typeof(RootPage),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public ObservableCollection<CustomText> CustomTextCollection
    { 
       get { return (ObservableCollection<CustomText>) GetValue(CustomTextCollectionProperty); } 
       set { SetValue(CustomTextCollectionProperty, value); }
    }  

    public RootPage ()
    {
        listView = new ListView() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand };
        CustomTextCollection = new ObservableCollection<CustomText>();
        CustomTextCollection.Add(new CustomText("asd", "bsd"));

        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCustomCell));
        //the part with binding
        var bind = new Binding() 
        { 
           Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = this, 
           Path = new PropertyPath("CustomTextCollection")
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(listView, ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, bind)
        //your other code...
    }
}
```

И теперь нужно сделать то же самое с RowHeight. Вы даже можете забиндить к созданному Вами свойству и значение слайдера (BindingMode.TwoWay) и к нему же высоту строки listView (здесь уже будет BindingMode.OneWay).

Comment: Что необходимо подключить, для использоваться  'DependencyProperty' , 'FrameworkPropertyMetadata()', 'PropertyPath', 'BindingOperations' ?

Comment: Для BindingOperations - System.Windows.Data, для всего остального - System.Windows. Это легко узнать из документации Microsoft. Кроме того, если вы работаете в Visual Studio, то там можно включить\настроить подсказчик, который упрощает подобные моменты.

Comment: Добавил скриншот с добавленными директориями, System.Windows.Data не знает. BindingOperations до сих пор неизвестен, а System.Windows ничем не используется. Подсказчик включен, но не предлагал включить эти директивы

Comment: Моя вина, написанный мной код - для WPF, а не Xamarin. В вашем случае есть похожий механизм BindableProperty (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty?view=xamarin-forms). Можно сказать, это то же самое, что DependencyProperty в WPF, но с другим названием.